# Undefined header express when trying to verify token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, http-headers

i've made an express backend and wanted to add some security using JsonWebToken npm library.

From the react app i'm using an interceptor to set the auth token on every request:

```
Axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("api_token") || "auth_pending";
  config.headers.Authorization =  token;
  console.log("Injected header token",token);
  return config;
});
```

And in my node backend, using express library i set a middleware for all requests except for login.

```
app.use(/\/((?!login).)*/, (req, res, next)=>{
   const {authorization} = req.headers;
   // console.log(authorization); next(); #If end function here the token is shown in the console.                     
   jwt.verify(authorization, '53CR37C0D3', function(err, decoded) {
      if(err){
         console.error(err);
         return res.status(403).send("Token is not valid.");
        }
    req.duser = decoded.user;
    res.status(200).send("Access granted.");
    next();
  });
```

});

As shown in the code, if i only use the middleware for logging the token it works fine. But if i want to decode it using JWT, authorization becomes **undefined**.
I assume it has something to do with cors preflight requests but i cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a middleware file isAuth.js and then you can implement it like this:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
const token = req.get("Authorization"); //get header from req by name 'Autherization'
 if (!token || token === "") {
    req.isAuth = false;
    return next();
  }

  try {
    let decoded = jwt.verify(token, "thisissecret");
    req.duser = decoded.user;
    res.status(200).send("Access granted.");
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(403).send("Token is not valid.");
  }
  req.isAuth = true;
  return next();
};
```

Finally, you can import and use it as a middleware like this:

```
const isAuth = require('/middleware/isAuth');
...
app.use(isAuth());
```

Comment: Thank you! The thing is, if i do that way i will have to implement a verification on each request, and that's what i want to simplify.

Comment: You don't have to implement for all request you can it as a middleware. Check it out i have updated my answer.